# i am using almofire 5 beta version for api call.i getting invalid parameters in response after passing the correct parameters

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, rest, alamofire

I am using almofire 5 beta version and getting invalid parameters error in api response
My code is :

```
let parameters: [String: String] = [
            "email" : "XXXXX@gmail.com",
            "first_name" : "XXX",
            "last_name" : "XXX",
            "provider": "XXX",
            "provider_id": "XXXX",
            "age" : "XXXXX"
        ]

    AF.request("https://XXXXX.app/public/api/XXXXXX", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default,, headers: ["XXXXXX" : "accesstoken"])
        .responseJSON { error in
           print(response)
    }
```

what is the reason?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try sending `encoding: URLEncoding.queryString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check several things first.

You can add 'Parameters' object. eg :-

```
let parameters: [Parameters] = [
        "email" : "XXXXX@gmail.com",
        "first_name" : "XXX",
        "last_name" : "XXX",
        "provider": "XXX",
        "provider_id": "XXXX",
        "age" : "XXXXX"
    ]
```

In your Hedears, you need to indicate parameter name first. eg :-

```
   ["accesstoken" : "xxxxx"]
```

Double check your Header name with backend (eg :- accesstoken, token .. etc)

Check what is the encoding type with Backend developer. you can use (URLEncoding.httpBody, URLEncoding.queryString, JSONEncoding.default ...)

Answer (score 0):

you insert two , symbol without any input key and value

try this

```
let parameters: [String: String] = [
        "email" : "XXXXX@gmail.com",
        "first_name" : "XXX",
        "last_name" : "XXX",
        "provider": "XXX",
        "provider_id": "XXXX",
        "age" : "XXXXX"
    ]

AF.request("https://XXXXX.app/public/api/XXXXXX", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["XXXXXX" : "accesstoken"])
    .responseJSON { error in
       print(response)
```

Comment: already this this code getting same error invalid parameters.

Comment: @masoud, Its pretty obvious that xcode should not allow you to run the code with double comma(,) and if the api is returning the error then its pretty clear that the code runs well without any error.

Comment: Try sending `encoding: URLEncoding.queryString` & `headers:["accesstoken": "123456"]`.

Comment: your header format is wrong and I check your web service api by postman and it's response

"error": {
        "message": "Please check HTTP Request Method. - MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
        "status_code": 403
    }

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code you need to pass encoding and header like below

```
encoding: URLEncoding.queryString,
headers: ["accesstoken": "XXXXXX"]
```

So, your final request will be

```
AF.request("https://XXXXXX.app/public/api/XXXXXX", method: .post, parameters: ["user_id": "XXXXXX"], encoding: URLEncoding.queryString, headers: ["accesstoken": "XXXXXX"]).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(_):
                print(response)

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
```

This code is working and printed the following output:

```
SUCCESS: {
    message = "XXXXXX";
    status = 1;
}
```